# How will I include a Java jar file when compiling a Java class and running the Java file from the command console?

Tags: java, jar, compilation

I have a small Java file interacting with a postgresql database,
so I've downloaded the drivers and in my file I import `org.postgresql.Driver`.

In the command console I type `javac Myfilename.java` ;
then it compiles I run `java Myfilename` and it throws an error saying it can not find the `org.postgresql.Driver` files.

So how do I import the jar when I run the file or when I compile the file not sure when the import should take place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compile:

```
javac -cp ".:postresql.jar" -d . MyFileName.java
```

Run:

```
java -cp ".:postresql.jar" MyFileName
```

Comment: this is for linux, in windows I believe it is `.;` instead of `.:`

Comment: @Hans you're right, Windows uses `;` as separator for PATH components.

Comment: @anubhava When I run the file I get an error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundExceptin: org.postgresql.Driver
What would the cause of this be?

Comment: Error came because jar file wasn't found. Please make sure jar file names is correct and jar file is present in the current directory. Is it Windows or Linux?

Comment: @anubhava http://pastebin.com/Rq6rSqx9 I've pasted the source code to the fiule there, and the jar file is postgresql.jar and the file is DatabaseTest.java both in the same directory.

Comment: Your code is fine. Are you saying you were able to compile and generate DatabaseTest.class class file but could not run?

Comment: Yes correct it doesn't seam to be able to find the org.postgresql.Driver so yes I can compile it but when I run it throws an error..

Comment: hmm It is quite weird that javac is able to find `postresql.jar` but java cannot with the same classpath specified.

Comment: Ok can you run this command `echo $CLASSPATH` (Linux) or `set CLASSPATH` (Windows) and tell me its output.

Comment: It says "Environment variable CLASSPATH not defined"

Comment: Ok good to know. Make sure you're running `java -cp ".;postresql.jar" DatabaseTest` command. ( note that it has `;` instead of `:`)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the driver jar to your build path while running.

Comment: How do I create a build path?

Comment: @Aaron.
Document to set a classpath for java.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html

Answer (score 1):

you need to list the filepaths of the included drivers

```
javac -cp "filepath.jar" MyFileName.java
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you can the environment variable `CLASSPATH` and append the jars to this `CLASSPATH` variable or you can use `java -cp` or `java -classpath` to run your code.

`javac -classpath C:\java\postresql.jar MyClass.java` or `javac -cp C:\java\postresql.jar MyClass.java`